# Regarding Jquery addition of onclick attribute dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

On clicking the link below, what I want is to change the onclick function like onclick="linkSubCategory(1, \'people\', \'1\', \'peopleLink\');" that is changing the third attribute to 1 from 0.

```
<a href="#" id="peopleLink" onclick="linkSubCategory(1, \'people\', \'0\', \'peopleLink\');" style="display: inline-block;"><img src="images/icons/group.png"></a>
```

For my above requirement I am using the code below but it is not working. Kindly suggest me a way to achieve my requirement.

```
function linkSubCategory(divID, divName, chkVal, linkID) {
$("#"+linkID).removeAttr("onclick");
        $("#"+linkID).attr("onclick", "linkSubCategory("+divID+", '"+divName+"', '1', '"+ linkID +"')");}
```

Comment: I think it would me more proper to store divId , divName, and chkval on the link using data attributes than passing them to the onclick function. Then you could do `$('#peoplelink').click(function(){divId=$(this).data('divId')...` and set the chkval accordingly. This way you don't neeed to rewrite the handler , just the data attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see things:

```
<a href="#" id="peopleLink" data-divid="1" data-divname="people" data-chkval="0" class="linkSubCategory" ></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.linkSubCategory').click(function(){
   linkSubCategory($(this).data('divid'), $(this).data('divname'), $(this).data('chkval'), this.id);
   $(this).data('chkval',1);
});
```

This way you don't need to change the event handler. Cause imo , changing the handler means you want to radically change the way it works, but here you just need to change a  parameter.